# Transforming from class_name to ClassName (and vice versa) in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

I could try and do this on my own, but since rails already deals with this so often I thought maybe there would be a helper for this.

I wanted a function that would take `"object_name"` and return `"ObjectName"` (and also do the inverse).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as you have active_support included (which it is in rails), the following will work on any ruby project:

```
"object_name".classify
```

Comment: Thanks! And the opposite? Is there already a function for that?

Comment: Had to look this one up :). It's `underscore`, used in the same way. Can refer to the docs here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-camelize